# After cheking 'use shared runtime' app does not work anymore mono

Tags: mono, xamarin

My app size is getting slightly big, I'm trying to shrink the size using 'use shared run-time' the app works fine without any error. However, when I check the 'use shared run-time' check-box i can create the apk file install it but it does not work on some devices that used to work. anybody know why this is so? thanks

Comment: Please include a logcat capture of the error.

Answer (score 14):

Please read this article carefully.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/

1. Shared runtime is used for debugging.
2. APKs relying on shared runtime expect the runtime to be installed separately, which is not the case if you deploy such APKs to Android markets.
3. Uncheck that box if you are building distribution APKs.

Comment: In that case the app size gets pretty big! is there any method to make it smaller? an empty app with Google services is more than 10 mg after it is installed!

Comment: Yes, that's the ABCs you should learn about Xamarin's solutions for iOS and Android, as they require a runtime which need to be packed with your app. If you think the extra MB is a problem for you, you obviously can use other vendors' tools. For most production apps on the market powered by Xamarin, such extra bits only give them a boost on productivity, and little trouble on app size.

Answer (score 0):

Once creating APK file in release mode open your .csproj file in notepad/notepad++

and find the tag **AndroidUseSharedRuntime** and set it to false.

Will work definitleyl